# PHP map file into virtual memory

Tags: php, file, memory-management, handle, virtual-memory

I am using PHP to handle some large files (around 500MB to 2 GB) where I need to write to small sections in unpredictable positions in the file. Is there a way to map the file to virtual memory so I do not have to make a `fwrite()` or `fread()` call? The major caveat is that it will be reading small chunks, but will be accessing a large amount of data in total, all within one file.

Comment: Whats the problem with `fwrite()`/`fread()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KingCrunch nails it on the head.. `fwrite`, `fread` and `fseek` really are the way to go..

The only reason I can think of why you may feel that you don't want to use them, is perhaps that they are a bit harder to use in PHP?

If this is the case, why not create a simple wrapper class that calls these methods internally..

**Edit based on comment**

With virtual memory, I understood the windows term, which is memory mapped to the filesystem. If you are concerned about performance, and you are fine placing the *entire file* into memory instead, there's two routes I can think off right now:

1. Create a tmpfs mount, and place the file there.
2. Use the `php://memory` stream, and place the entire file in there with `stream_copy_to_stream`.

You can also just do a file_get_contents, which also gives you the entire stream in memory, but I can definitely imagine that both tmpfs and php://memory will give you better performance and memory efficiency. I would personally go for the tmpfs mount.

Comment: The problem really isn't difficulty, but performance. I have a file up to 2 GB and mapping it in virtual memory can speed it up. Of course, if I can't ,then I'll just take this.

Comment: So there is no way mapping it to virtual memory without putting it in physical memory? I'll find a way to work around.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Are you really asking, if it is possible to put something into the memory, without putting something into the memory? I really suggests to first stick with the filesystem and test, wether or not the performance is really that bad. Processing 2GB takes it time independent from where you read it...

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: yea you are completely missing the point of virtual memory then.

Comment: OK... I was referring more to mapping than virtual memory(not really overhead, but bandwidth)

Comment: Be very specific in your question. It's also better to measure first and then figure out what you need to improve.